# Ifelse function R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying execute this code but getting result NA.

```
> node1<- paste0("train$", rule, collapse=" & ")
> node1
[1] "train$feat_11< 5.477 & train$feat_60< 4.687"
>x<-ifelse(node1,1,0)
[1] NA
```

How can I use character vector in if else function?

Comment: You will have to evaluate this expression first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logical vectors and character vectors are two very different things in R.

```
class(node1)
#>[1] "character"
```

You must first parse and evaluate the string.

```
lNode1 = eval(parse(text=node1))
class(lNode1)
#>[1] "logical"
x<-ifelse(lNode1,1,0)
#>a list of 1's and 0's
```

That being said, however, your `ifelse` statement is redundant.  A logical vector will coerce to an integer vector when used in a fashion that requires it.  For example, you can `sum(lNode1)` and get the number of times you pass both rules.

Comment: Note that this isn’t great R code. R has better tools for dynamic evaluation, such as `formula`. Constructing and subsequently parsing a string is almost always the least appealing solution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've seen that sentiment posted many times before (I still don't understand *why*, though) - but here, I don't know how else to take the character string and turn it into code that will evaluate as a logical vector.  Further, `as.formula(node1)` returns: `Error in formula.default(eval(parse(text = x)[[1L]])) : invalid formula` which would suggest that `formula` is identical to `eval(parse(text=node1))` - so how is *this* bad code?

Comment: @Mark You wouldn’t take a character string in the first place, you’d pass a `formula` or similar into the function. After all, that’s how e.g. `lm` does it. As for why it’s bad, there are a host of reasons. Foremost, parsing and evaluating strings always carries a security risk if there’s even the slightest chance that user input may end up in the string. It’s also inefficient. It also subverts the type system (but that’s pathetically weak in R anyway) — aka. “stringly typed code”. More fundamentally, though, it’s simply a conceptually convoluted solution because it takes a huge detour.

Comment: @KonradRudolph how would you solve this problem then?  I'd be happy to modify my answer to include good R code (and learn myself in the process).

Comment: @Mark Without knowing more about OP’s use-case we can’t, which is why I’ve written a comment rather than an answer. Your answer is the best we can do here, I’m just suggesting that OP’s approach is almost certainly suboptimal.